# Foreign key Entity Framework - code first migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I have a problem with my entities. I'm using EF code-first migrations and the migrations are failing with this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_OrdersChildsProducts_Orders_OrderId' on table 'OrdersChildsProducts' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Here's my PersonJceProfile entity :

```
[Table("PersonJceProfiles")]
public class PersonJceProfile : BaseEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("Ces")]
    public int? CeId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public PersonJceProfile()
    {
        Children = new List<Child>();
    }
}
```

Here's my Order entity :

```
[Table("Orders")]
public class Order : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //ForeignKey
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("PersonJceProfiles")]
    public int PersonJceProfileId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsSecurePayment { get; set; }
    public int LeftToPayPersonOrder { get; set; }
    public string Delivery { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderChildProduct> OrderChildProduct { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        OrderChildProduct = new Collection<OrderChildProduct>();
    }
}
```

Here's my Child entity :

```
[Table("Childrens")]
public class Child :BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public bool? IsActif { get; set; }

    public decimal AmountParticipationCe { get; set; }

    public bool? IsRegrouper { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("PersonJceProfiles")]
    public int PersonJceProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my Product Entity

```
public class Product : Good
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDisplayedOnJCE { get; set; }
    public bool? IsBasicProduct { get; set; }
    public int? PintelSheetId { get; set; }
    public int OriginId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Suppliers")]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }

}
```

Here's my OrderChildProduct entity :

```
 [Table("OrdersChildsProducts")]
public class OrderChildProduct
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int LeftToPayChildOrder { get; set; }

    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

Here's my context :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OrderChildProduct>().HasKey(ccp => new { ccp.OrderId, ccp.ChildId, ccp.ProductId });
```

I suppose i do destro a relationship like this :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
.HasRequired(c => c.ForeignKey)
.WithMany()
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

but I can't see between which. Because

- When I delete PersonJceProfiles : Order must be deleted - OrderChildProduct must be deleted - Child must be deleted
- When I delete Order : OrderChildProduct must be deleted
- When I delete Order childProduct :  nothing must be deleted expect himself

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is self described. You must configure the relationships in the `OrderChildProduct` table like:

```
entity.HasOne(p => p.Order)
    .WithMany(p => p.OrderChildProduct)
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.OrderId)
    .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

You can use either `Restrict` or `Cascade` depending on your requirements.
Also the other 2 relationships must be defined as well.

This is not an error. This is more like a warning... the way EF tells you that it doesn't fully understand the relationships and you must configure them manually.